# Edited most errors, Now Compiles, but does not Run, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c++

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::string;
using std::setprecision;
using std::fixed;

//function prototypes     
void getInput(string &, double);
void calcFedTaxes(double , double, double &, double &);
void calcnetPay(double &,  double , double, double);
void displayInfo(string, double, double, double);

int main()
{   
    //declare constants and variables
    const double FWT_RATE  = .2;
    const double FICA_RATE = .08;
    string dname    = "";
    double dsalary  = 0.0;
    double dfwtTax  = 0.0; 
    double dficaTax = 0.0;
    double dnetPay  = 0.0;

    //display output in fixed-point notation with two decimal places
    cout << fixed << setprecision(2);

    //call function to get input and calculate salary and taxes 
    void getInput(string dname, double dsalary, double dnetPay);

    void calcFedTaxes(double Fsalary, double FwtRate, double FicaRate,
            double & withholdingTax, double & incomeTax); 

    void calcnetPay(double & netPay, double weeklySalary, double fwtTax,
        double ficaTax); 

    void displayInfo (string dname, double dfwtTax, double dficaTax, 
            double dnetPay);

    system ("pause");

}   //end call function


//*****function definitions*****

void getInput(string iname, double isalary)
{
    //enter input items
    cout << "Enter name: ";
    cin >> iname;
    cout << "weekly salary: ";
    cin >> isalary;
}

void calcFedTaxes (double Fsalary, double FwtRate,  double FicaRate, 
        double & withholdingTax, double & incomeTax)
{
    withholdingTax = Fsalary * FwtRate;
    incomeTax      = Fsalary * FicaRate;     
}

void calcnetPay(double & netPay, double weeklySalary, double fwtTax, 
        double ficaTax)
{
    netPay = weeklySalary - fwtTax - ficaTax;
}

void displayInfo(string dname, double dfwtTax,  double dficaTax, 
        double dnetPay)
{
    cout << "name: " << dname;
    cout << "With holding Tax: " << dfwtTax;
    cout << "With holding Fica: "<<dficaTax;
    cout << "Net pay: " <<dnetPay;
    cin>> dnetPay;

    //end of displayInfo function

    return;
}
```

Comment: It's a linking error. Name the compiler and the libraries you are using.

Answer (score 5):

Your code is referencing functions which it does not provide. (That's only a link error because those functions may well be provided by some other library you might be linking with.)

(without any code posted) You presumably have a separate header file which defines prototypes of getInput and displayInfo. Make sure that your definitions of getInput and displayInfo actually match those prototypes! Note that

```
void getInput(std::string &foo, double &bar)
```

is different than

```
void getInput(std::string foo, double bar)
```

and also, of course,

```
void getInpoot(std::string &foo, double &bar)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just from a casual glance, I notice two obvious mistakes.

The first is an argument mismatch between the prototype and definition of `getInput()`

```
void getInput(string &, double &) ;
void getInput(string iname , double isalary)
```

where the prototype is expecting references, but the definition is not.

The second one is a bit more obvious once you see it.  A simple typo where the function name is missing an "a" in the `displayInfo()` definition.

```
void displyInfo(string dname, double dfwtTax,  double dficaTax, 
    double dnetPay)
```

Answer (score 1):

In `main`,

```
//call function to get input and calculate salary and taxes
void getInput(string dname, double dsalary, double dnetPay);

void calcFedTaxes(double Fsalary, double FwtRate, double FicaRate,
        double & withholdingTax, double & incomeTax); 

void calcnetPay(double & netPay, double weeklySalary, double fwtTax,
        double ficaTax); 

void displayInfo (string dname, double dfwtTax, double dficaTax, 
        double dnetPay);
```

does not do what you think it does.

What you have done is given prototypes for functions.  This generates no code and does not call any functions.

You probably meant

```
// call functions to get input and calculate salary and taxes
getInput(dname, dsalary, dnetPay);

double withholdingTax, incomeTax;
calcFedTaxes(dsalary, FWT_RATE, FICA_RATE, withholdingTax, incomeTax);
```

et cetera.  These functions that you are trying to call do not match the functions you have actually defined, which you must also fix.

Comment: Apologies - here are the includes
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

Comment: Well, you call `system` whose prototype is in `<cstdlib>`.  Even though it either gets pulled in through another header or works without a proper prototype, you should still `#include` the correct header.

Comment: Thank You, I am halfway through fixing, I will be right back, I noticed where I had messed up! :)

Answer (score 1):

In main(), you are only prototype functions, not calling them:

```
//call function to get input and calculate salary and taxes 
void getInput(string dname, double dsalary, double dnetPay);
```

That defines a function, now you need to call it:

```
getInput(dname, dsalary, dnetPay);
```

That said, your code is confusing.  Let's look at the three current references to getInput in your code:

```
void getInput(string &, double);
void getInput(string dname, double dsalary, double dnetPay);
void getInput(string iname, double isalary) { ... }
```

You have two prototypes, both of which have different signatures then your function definition.  Until you get that cleaned up, you are going to continue having trouble.

Answer (score 0):

These aren't standard library functions, do you know where they come from - probably something in your environment/compiler.

You need to link with the libraries, in visual studio see properties->linker->input->additional dependencies, on uinx you will have to pass '-lnameoflibrary' to the compiler